# Using the Lutz reflector for seeing IL code

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a class with a few methods and I would like to see how the code is converted to IL code. Can I do this using the reflector? If not, can I use VS IDE to view the IL code?

Comment: As of August 2008 .Net Reflector is owned by Red Gate Software, no longer Lutz Roeder. http://reflector.red-gate.com/

Comment: I'm wondering about the second question here: can VS display the IL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. Open the exe/dll with Reflector and change the language setting to IL.

Comment: Excellent, got it. On a side note, by changing the language, we can use the reflector as a language convertor? (say from C# to VB.NET)

Comment: Yes, kind of. It doesn't always work, as there are some things in C# that don't map well to VB, for example, things like iterators, but generally speaking, you can use it as a converter. The following Reflector Add-On will convert a whole assembly into source files of the desired language: http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) to disassemble the assembly to IL.